# JSF Form From Entity and Foreign Key Issue

Tags: jsf, netbeans

Recently I did [CRUD Enterprise Application in NetBeans][1.] I made my own scenario for it namely storing scores for player. I have tree tables player, game and playerGame table. Every thing works fine with player and game table (add, remove, edit) as in tutorial form youtube but, I have problem with linked table (playerGame). When I try generate JSF Form From Entity using netBeans Palette I am getting this code

`<h:selectOneMenu id="fkGameId" value="#{controller.playerGame.fkGameId}" title="FkGameId" required="true" requiredMessage="The FkGameId field is required.">
                        <!-- TODO: update below reference to list of available items-->
                        <f:selectItems value="#{fixme}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>`

Also I have tried this

```
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="fkPlayerId" value="#{controller.player.playerId}" title="FkPlayerId" required="true" requiredMessage="The FkPlayerId field is required.">
                    <!-- TODO: update below reference to list of available items-->
                    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.player.playerGameList}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

but with no result

in place where foreign keys to playerId and gameId should be inputed by palette.

My question is what I have to do to fix this, it would be nice to see similar example on linked tables but I didn't found anything (only one simple table examples I have found) I am newbie in JavaEE and this was my first tutorial ever in this subject and to be honest I don't know how to name thing properly.

Also trying to find the solution for the problem I did JavaServer Faces tutorial form netbeans website [Generating JSF CRUD Application form Databases](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html). The tutorial was pretty straight forward and I had no problem with it and it works fine with the same scenario (I was able to select foreign keys form dropdown list and create playerGame record). I have tried solve this problem based on JSF pages form this tutorial but the pages are generated using netBeans command JSF Pages form Entity Classes I because I have no experience in Java EE like mentioned before I have failed to solve the problem.

P.S. I you need me to provide more information please just ask.

UPDATE:

It is partially working now thanks to Geinmachi

Partial SOLUTION:

In my controller class I have added

```
    private String playerList;

public String getPlayerList() {
    return playerList;
}

public void setPlayerList(String playerList) {
    this.playerList = playerList;
}



private List<Player> playerLists;

public List<Player> getPlayerLists() {
    return playerLists;
}

public void setPlayerLists(List<Player> playerLists) {
    this.playerLists = playerLists;
}


@PostConstruct
public void init(){
   playerLists = playerFacade.findAll();
    // playerLists = new ArrayList<>();
   // playerLists.add( new Player(player.getPlayerId()));
}
public void submit(){
    System.out.println("Selected Player: " + playerList);
}
```

and my jsf code looks like

```
                    <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{controller.playerList}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{player.playerName}"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.playerLists}" var="player" itemValue="#{player.playerId}" itemLabel="#{player.playerName}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

the was found in one of links given by Geinmachi.

However now I am getting `javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted`
 when trying to insert data to database because partial solution doesn't get fk_game_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given fields in `PlayerGame` entity (with getters/setters)

- `private Player fkPlayerId`
- `private Game fkGameId`

In controller:

- `private List<Player> playerList`
- `private List<Game> gameList`

form:

```
<h:form>
        <h:outputText value="Choose player"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{controller.playerGame.fkPlayerId}" converter="playerConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{controller.playerList}" var="player" 
                           itemValue="#{player}" itemLabel="#{player.playerName}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputText value="Choose Game"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{controller.playerGame.fkGameId}" converter="gameConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{controller.gameList}" var="game" 
                           itemValue="#{game}" itemLabel="#{game.gameName}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton action="#{controller.createPlayerGame}" value="Link player with a game"/>
    </h:form>
```

In your controller you need lists of all players and all games to choose from. You have to create converters for entities because on the HTML page they are just `String` and JSF expects `Player` and `Game` objects. For POJO JSF converter you can search in google and read [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html)

**See:**

- [h:selectOneMenu wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: In my PlayerGame.java I have private Player fkPlayerId. You mean this field etc.?

Comment: Yes, in this case you need converter.

Comment: I did found also this [netbeans link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevelopJavaEE6App#Creating_the_Enterprise_Application_Projects) there is getDiscountCodes method, so I have to create something similar in my controller class right ??

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can just bind a `List` to `<f:selectItems>`, no need to create programmatic model.

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. If you have entites in `h:selectOneMenu` you need converter, you should find plenty of examples in google when searching for "jsf converter".

Comment: It is working now Big thanks for help